# Properties file in JavaScript / Angular

Tags: javascript

In Java I usually create `application.properties` in my resource folder and put configs in there.

And when I need it I just do `Properties prop = new Properties(); prop.load(... my file)` and then use `prop.getProperty("Something")`

I want to do something similar in Javascript

In my js code I have this:

```
// REST API Base URL
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8083/api";
```

I want this to be in a application.properties file and then load the value.

How can I achive this?

Thanks

Comment: Create a file constants.js. Put every env var you wanna use in it and let it be the first file included by your app.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm starting to have parkisson syndrome after doing a app in js

Comment: Think of you have constants.java that you hold your global vars in it. Same consept. Except for js files, you need to include them into your html, right? So just be sure that that file is your very first file included in your html code.

Answer (score 3):

In angular 2+ projects and for a good practices you should create  environments folder with one file per env like: environment.ts, environment.prod.ts.

and into file you can export a constant or by default like that

```
export const environment = {
  apiUrl: '',
  googleApiKey: '',
}
```

and you can import  this environment in every file you will needed like

```
import { environment } from '{relativePath}/environment/environment.ts'
```

If you create different files for every env like prod. You need to replace environment.js for env that you will be build. You have lot of info about this with webpack or other compilers.

I recommend you strongly to develop into a common.js project. It will be more friendly for you importing modules and you will have powerful possibilities of scalable app.

But the easy(Ugly) solution is:

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="environment.js">
  <script src="app.js">
</head>
```

environment.js

```
// Declaring environment like that you will have window scoped the variable
// and you will have global access to environment with window.environment
var environment = {apiUrl: 'https://api.url:4100'}
```

app.js

```
function example(){
  console.log(window.environment.apiUrl); // out https://api.url:4100
}
```

Comment: It's angularJS sorry

Comment: Well this solution is not angular2+ restriction is just javascript

Comment: I can see that you are talking about two different things here, the first is used in built cycle while the second is more like an api stored in global object that can be changed before you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on how you build and/or bundle your AngularJs application. But regardless of that, you'll need to create a config.json file to contain your settings.
If using browserify or webpack, you can import that file via require(...), otherwise you can simply request it via ajax before your app bootstraps.

In any of these cases, the best way to use the configuration data throughout your app is to define it as a constant at the bootstrap phase: `app.constant('CONFIG', configData);`, assuming that configData is a variable that contains the data from your config.json file.

Then you can use dependency injection to provide CONFIG to all your controllers, services and directives.